# Determining uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+x n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm looking to show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+x n}$ converges uniformly for all $x>-1$. Typically I would use the Weierstrass M-test that requires a series of numbers that is greater in size for all $x$ and all $n$. I cannot seem to find a series that will work for both all $n$ and all $x>-1$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n^2 + xn > n^2 -n$, so for $n \geq 2$ we have $\frac 1 {n^2 + xn} < \frac 1 {n^2 -n}$. Therefore, if you separate the first term from the others (this does not affect (uniform) convergence) you get: $\frac 1 {1+x} + \sum \limits _{n=2} ^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^2 + xn} \leq \frac 1 {1+x} + \sum \limits _{n=2} ^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^2 - n} \leq \frac 1 {1+x} + \sum \limits _{n=2} ^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^2 - 2n +1} = \frac 1 {1+x} + \sum \limits _{n=2} ^{\infty} \frac 1 {(n-1)^2} = \frac 1 {1+x} + \frac {\pi ^2} 6$ (so $M_n = \frac 1 {(n-1)^2}$, but only for $n \geq 2$). You don't really need the value $\frac {\pi ^2} 6$, the important thing is that $\sum \limits _{n=2} ^{\infty} \frac 1 {(n-1)^2}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ working ?

Comment: When n=1 we divide by zero though? Doesnt the M-test require the series to work for all n?

Comment: If it works for $n$ large enough it's OK, since we're studying limits.